# How to resize the keyboard display in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

I want to resize the keyboard display with in the screen.. if i type into the textbox or texfield, the keyboard display will fully covered the screen.so please suggest how to use to resize the keyboard display

Comment: Maybe [Tutorial: Moving native text input fields/boxes](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/11/18/tutorial-moving-native-textfieldtextbox-objects/) helps.

Comment: Its only help to resize the textbox size. but i need to resize virtual keyboard size when we type on the textfield/box